# prove that the limit of the given piecewise function does not exist, using the formal definition.

Tags: calculus, limits

i'm having problem with this exercise. Can somebody give me a hint ?

The function is 
*f(x)* = 
\begin{cases}
x^{2},  & \text{if x ≤ 2 } \\
8 - 2x, & \text{if 2 < x}
\end{cases}

is given that the  $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x)$ does not exist. but how i prove with the formal definition ?

i use the definition ∀ε > 0 ∃δ > 0 : | x ∋ (a,b), *0<|x-x'|<δ* and *|f(x) - L|<ε*

and tried, first fixing *ε = 0.1 ,* *x'= 2* then applying *|1.9 - 2|< δ* => *δ > 0.1* and *|4.2 - 4| < ε* => *ε > 0.2* so by this result the limit exist ?! 
Thanks.

edit: I misunderstood the concept of the existence of a limit and if the function can be derived. then yes the limit exist. But still in my professor problem are saying that the limit does not exist. Translating it is says literaly "*prove by the formal definition why the lim does not exist*". Probably he was playing with the class to see what we would answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, during translation something seems  to have been lost. The limit *exists* at $x = 2$, and in fact this function is continuous everywhere, including at $2$.

Comment: you are right, i bet the professor was probably playing with us making this kind of affirmation in the problem. Just to see what we would answer.

Comment: I see. Also, to close  the question, either write an answer yourself and accept it after some time, or accept the answer below when you can (if you like it, but there is everything to like about it): this will automatically close the question.

Comment: did it, thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome! +1 for the question, and providing attention to answers/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that indeed

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 2^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 2^-} f(x)=4$$

therefore the limit exists and you can proceed with the definition to prove that.

Comment: Oh i made a huge mistake! on my interpretation.

Comment: translating it is says literaly "_prove by the formal definition why the lim does not exist_".

Comment: @JeremiasJunior Yes but here the limit exists, there we can't prove that!

Comment: for sure he playing with the class, by giving this kind of affirmation. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe it is a typo for the question or for the function. You can prove at first by definition that it exists and the taking  $f(x)=8-3x$ for $x>2$ prove by definiiton that it doesn't exist.

Comment: is possible to close the topic ? i think it is nothing more to say about.

Comment: @JeremiasJunior Yes of course you can delete the question by yourself if you do not want to chenge that and try to solve in another way. Bye